# How to avoid "Name 're' is not defined" error while connecting pycharm remote debugger?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

After removing a line of regex from my code I started to get this error message in the console when connecting PyCharm's remote debugger. After this, the application appears to work correctly (the debugger connects and the code runs normally), but I cannot find the source of this error.

I am using Python 2.7, with the PyCharm 2 debugger.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycharm-debug.egg/pydev/pydevd_comm.py", line 824, in doIt
        result = pydevd_vars.evaluateExpression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycharm-debug.egg/pydev/pydevd_vars.py", line 406, in evaluateExpression
        Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycharm-debug.egg/pydev/pydevd_exec.py", line 2, in Exec
        exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: It would help if you provide the code that crashes. It is strange that it used to work but not anymore...

Comment: The removed line be responsible for creating a variable by the name 're'. You can prove it by adding something like 're = None' or check your original line.